# iPhone to host server to mySQL and back?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

Can someone please direct me to process for doing this? I have already done the Login verification exercise using mySQL for the dbase on my host server (thanks to kiksy). Now I am trying to move forward and "Query" from the iPhone a list of "users" that currently occupy the table (iphoneusers) in MySQL. And of course get it back to the iPhone via the php connection.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

ronbowalker

Comment: are you writing a native iPhone App or a web based app for iPhone?? I would assume you are using PHP for a web based app...

Answer (score 0):

your query can be as simple as this:

```
 SELECT `users` FROM iphoneusers LIMIT 0, 30;
```

in PHP... However, i'm quite unsure how your setup is like? Are you writing a native iPhone app or a PHP application that serves as an intermediate between your iPhone app and the database.